# SQL: SELECT TOP with ORDER BY clause does not return correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SELECT TOP query with an ORDER BY clause that does not return the correct result. Below is a sample query and its output.

Any suggestion / workaround / solution ?

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTop
(
    TopID INT,
    TopStr VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1749, '');
INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1750, '');
INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1752, 'z');
INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1739, 'a');

SELECT * FROM #TestTop ORDER BY TopStr ASC

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #TestTop ORDER BY TopStr ASC

SELECT TOP 4 * FROM #TestTop ORDER BY TopStr ASC

DROP TABLE #TestTop;
```

Result:

```
[SELECT *]

TopID       TopStr
----------- -----------
1749        
1750        
1739        a
1752        z       

[SELECT TOP 1]

TopID       TopStr
----------- --------------
1750        

[SELECT TOP 4]

TopID       TopStr
----------- --------------
1750        
1749        
1739        a
1752        z
```

Comment: Why is the result incorrect? TopStr is allways blank. What is your expected result?

Comment: As per the SELECT * result; SELECT TOP 1 should return 1749 and SELECT TOP 4 should return 1749,1750,1752,1739.

Comment: then y r u adding order by topstr asc

Comment: but you're ordering by TopStr. If you want the order in your above comment you should be ordering by TopID

Comment: SQL Server does not guarantee the order of the results unless the order is explicitly defined. In your case, even if you have defined an order, your ordering data is `''`.

Comment: The results (even after your edit) are exactly as expected. The only way to guarantee the order of results is to give an unambiguous `ORDER BY` definition. If the `ORDER BY` doesn't mention a column, then that column is irrelevant to the order in which results will be returned. Tables have *no* inherent or natural order.

Comment: So you want 1752 before 1739, even though z sorts after a? Can you explain why the order you expect is 1749, 1750, 1752, 1739?

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at DevD. Even though the results are ordered, they are not ordered consistently when TopStr are not distinct. To get consistent results, order by both columns: (TopStr, TopId). That will sort by TopStr *and* be consistent. Also see my tongue in cheek article http://michaeljswart.com/2013/09/without-order-by-you-cant-depend-on-the-order-of-results/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Try this, it works in sql server

```
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM #TestTop 
order by ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (CASE WHEN TopStr = '' THEN NULL ELSE TopStr END))
```

OR

```
SET ROWCOUNT 4
SELECT * FROM #TestTop ORDER BY TopStr ASC
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: @DevD - if it "works" for you, it does so purely be coincidence. It may return different results the next time you run it.

Comment: Since the `TopID` values appear to be important in defining what the "correct" results are, any query that doesn't even mention `TopID` in the `ORDER BY` clause can't be correct.

Comment: Just because it happens to give the result the OP expects does not mean that it is a correct, or useful solution. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever has said it is coincidence, and there is no inherent order to the data in a table (especially a heap table), so unless there is a deterministic order by clause, the order is not deterministic. It is no more useful than saying a workaround would be `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #TestTop WHERE TopID = 1749`, from the sample data this would give the result the OP expects, but doesn't address the actual issue they are facing.

Answer (score 9):

You have not specified complete ordering, so the database (whichever one it is) is entitled to return rows that match on TopStr in any order it wants. Just because your first query happens to give the ordering you want is luck, and that could change based on a database upgrade / load on the system / many other factors.

You need to add the TopId into the ordering list if you want results to be ordered by that column as well as TopStr.

Comment: The actual table contains text data in TopStr column. Updated the query in the question.

Comment: @mc110: Please stop making only very small and minor edits to other posts. It is great that you like to improve posts. But since you are below 2k rep your edits need to be approved by at least 3 people. Please make these edits worth the time and improve **everything** that is wrong with a post. If that is only a very little thing then leave it to high-rep users. Thanks.

Comment: @juergen d: sincere apologies, I had not realised that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the column that's been used for sorting: the original statements use the `TopStr` column and, since all its values are equal, the order in which the rows are returned is unspecified. To correct your statement just use the proper column `TopID`, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTop
(
    TopID INT,
    TopStr VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1749, '');
INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1750, '');
INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1752, '');
INSERT INTO #TestTop VALUES(1739, '');

SELECT '' [_ALL_],* FROM #TestTop ORDER BY TopID ASC
SELECT TOP 1 '' [TOP_1], * FROM #TestTop ORDER BY TopID ASC
SELECT TOP 4 '' [TOP_4], * FROM #TestTop ORDER BY TopID ASC

DROP TABLE #TestTop;
```

Comment: The actual table contains text data in TopStr column. Updated the query in the question.